# message: 'Missing required parameter: status.', twitterReply: { errors: [ [Object] ] }, statusCode: 403,

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

For reference the full code  (please ignore my attempts for scheduling)

```
var config = require("./config.js");
var Twit = require('twit');
var TT = new Twit(config);

///dt.setDate(25);
//console.log(dt)
var d = new Date();
const d1 = new Date('December 12, 2020 00:00:00');
const d2 = new Date('December 12, 2020 00:00:00');
const d3 = new Date('December 12, 2020 00:00:00');
//const dt = new Date('December 24, 2020 00:00:00');

 d1.setDate(25);
 d2.setDate(26);
 d3.setDate(27);
 


    

tweetIt();
setInterval(tweetIt, 86400000)

function tweetIt(){
  
  
  var calc = d1.getDate() - d.getDate();

if (d < d1.getDate()) { 
    var tweet = calc + " days left until Christmas! Ho Ho Ho!"
}
 else if(d == d1.getDate() && d < d2.getDate()) { 
     var tweet = "Today is Christmas! Ho Ho Ho! "
  }
    else if(d == d2.getDate() && d < d3.getDate()){
        var tweet = "Today is Christmas! Ho Ho Ho! "
    }
     else { console.log(tweet);}

TT.post('statuses/update', {status: tweet}, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success: ' + data.text);
      //console.log(response);
    }
  };
  
}
```

I tried different ways of getting the Twitter status to actually send something. One of the things I tried doing was to set `var tweet = { status: "Hello!"}` or just `var tweet = "Hello 2 "` (as it is in the code). Also when I do `console.log(tweet)` it shows `undefined` and I can't figure out why it isn't reading any of the declared parameters.

Also for another reference - the code before this one (currently the one running on my server, and works perfectly fine) / code 2

```
var config = require("./config.js");
var Twit = require('twit');
var T = new Twit(config);

tweetIt();
setInterval(tweetIt, 86400000)

function tweetIt(){
var d = new Date();
var calc = 25 - d.getDate();
var tweet =  calc + " days left until Christmas! Ho Ho Ho! ❄⛄";

T.post('statuses/update', { status: tweet }, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success: ' + data.text);
      //console.log(response);
    }
  };
}
```

I can't understand why code 1 doesn't work, because I used code 2 as a template for code 1. Help is highly appreciated!

Edit: Please, keep in mind that I'm a beginner!

Comment: `if (d < d1.getDate()) { ... }` is it okay that you are comparing an `object` with an `integer`? please consider checking the values. `d` is an object and `d1.getDate()` return an `int`.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me! The code is now working!